# Image not rendering after TYPO3 upgrade

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

Today I have done one typo3 upgrade from 4.5 to 6.2. Initially from 4.5 to 4.7 everything was working fine with out any issues. After upgrading TYPO3 6.2 content elements like textimage and image only are not rendering . Can any one please tell me why this is happening? The below given typoscript is used to rendering banner images in the website. Can any one give me a hint?

```
#####################
### lib.keyVisual   #
#####################
lib.keyVisual = COA
lib.keyVisual {

    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5.maxImageWidth = 960
    5.maxImageWidthInText = 960

    50 = RECORDS
    50.source.current = 1
    50.tables = tt_content

    # remove all divs from textpic rendering
    50.conf.tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.15.value = item
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.layout >
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.layout = TEXT
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.layout.value = ###IMAGES######TEXT###
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.imageStdWrap.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.imageStdWrapNoWidth.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.imageColumnStdWrap.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.simple.imageStdWrapNoWidth.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.simple.imageStdWrap.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.simple.imageStdWrapNoWidth.wrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.dl.imageStdWrapNoWidth.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.dl.imageStdWrap.dataWrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.rendering.dl.imageStdWrapNoWidth.wrap = 
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.text.wrap.cObject = CASE
    50.conf.tt_content.textpic.20.text.wrap.cObject {
        key.field = imageorient
        key.stdWrap.wrap = |+1
        key.prioriCalc = 1

        1 = TEXT
        1.value = <div class="item-position1"> | </div>

        2 = TEXT
        2.value = <div class="item-position2"> | </div>

        9 = TEXT
        9.value = <div class="item-position3"> | </div>

        4 = TEXT
        4.value = <div class="item-position4"> | </div>

        default = TEXT
        default.value = <div class="item-position-default item-position-{field:imageorient}"> | </div>
        default.insertData = 1
    }


    100 = RESTORE_REGISTER

    wrap.required = 1
    wrap (
<div id="page-hero" class="page-hero">
    <div class="slides_container">
        |
    </div>
    <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
    <a class="next" href="#"></a>
</div>
)

}
```

BR
Siva

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the function IMAGE($conf) that fails to render it. You can debug it in typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php

If it's not that exact one it might be IMGTEXT or a similar one.

Answer (score -2):

After an upgrade from TYPO3 4.x to 6.2 you must perform several steps to get the images back.

1. Install Tool - Configuration presets: Image handling settings -> Use the detected (marked green) Image Magick or Graphics Magick
2. Install Tool - Test Setup and make some of the image tests
3. Install Tool - Clean Up: cache_imagesizes
4. Install Tool - Clean Up: Clear processed files
5. TYPO3 Backend - File Module: Click on the Filelist. This will load all images found there into the File Abstraction Layer (FAL)

Comment: don't do step 5 before you have run all upgrade wizards

Comment: As I have written, my 5 steps are to be performed "after an upgrade". The execution of the upgrade wizard is part of the upgrade as the name says. It is not part of the question asked here.

Comment: Many people forget to do that. Properly the root case is, that the ``reference index`` index was not update before the upgrade, which causes several ``upgrade wizards`` to overlook data. You answer will just make thinks worse.

Comment: Hello pgampe, what about opening an issue on the TYPO3 bug tracker? My answer has been working in my case to get the images shown.

Comment: ? the reference index needs to be updated prior to update, which is part of the upgrade guidelines. Where do you see a bug here?

Comment: Hello pgampe, if the reference index will be broken if you forgot to do anything, then I consider this as a bug of TYPO3. TYPO3 must be able to handle any case. TYPO3 must not force the user to do manual steps before an upgrade. It must do everything automatically by the upgrade wizard and it must be able to recover from any wrong step the user does. Otherwise it is a bug or a severe pitfall.

Comment: Just follow the doc! https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/UpgradeLTS/Preparation/Index.html#reference-index